# Approach for performing XSLT transformation on SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xslt

I am trying to perform XSLT transformation for converting a XML to different XML format. I am also using Xslt Extension Objects to perform data mapping operations during transformation.

I have mentioned a cut down version of XML formats below. There is a mapping table which maps the Supplier Product Code with ProductID in my system. So while transforming I use the extension objects to do such mapping operations.

This works well till the time I get a big XML document with couple of 1000's of detail nodes in it. In such scenario the extension object have performance impact.

I was wondering whether I can shift XSLT transformation to SQL Server and handle the data mapping operation at the DB level rather than making individual DB call from Extension Objects?

**Source XML Document**

```
<SuppliersDocument>
  <SupplierProducts>
    <Product>
      <ProductCode>A001</ProductCode>
      <UOM>KG</UOM>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ProductCode>A002</ProductCode>
      <UOM>ML</UOM>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ProductCode>A003</ProductCode>
      <UOM>EA</UOM>
    </Product>
  </SupplierProducts>
</SuppliersDocument>
```

**Target XML Document**

```
<MyDocument>
  <Products>
    <Product>
      <ProductID>998998</ProductID>
      <UnitOfMeasurementID>1</UnitOfMeasurementID>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ProductID>885855</ProductID>
      <UnitOfMeasurementID>2521</UnitOfMeasurementID>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <ProductID>225235</ProductID>
      <UnitOfMeasurementID>5542</UnitOfMeasurementID>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</MyDocument>
```

Comment: IMO the problem there is the fact that your extension objects are fetching data; I would recommend doing a scan over the data for *additional* data you need (i.e. looking for the IDs), and do a *single* query to fetch that data and make it available...

Comment: I agree with @Marc Gravell: query the data base once. How to use the XML source for the query? You could transform this XML into an SQL query (this would be very standard, very platform independent) or could use some of the SQL-Server extensions.

Comment: @Alejandro: Your approach is excellent and would be implemented in second release of the framework. @Marc: I am following  your approach by pass the source xml document to the extension object constructor. Once the entire document is with the extension object, I do the scanning in one go.

Answer (score 2):

### C# code:

```
public partial class StoredProcedures{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void CKTransfrom(out string resultXML, string inputXML, string transformXSL){
    XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();
    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(transformXSL)){
        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr)){
            proc.Load(xr);
        }
    }
    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(inputXML)){
        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr)){
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()){
                proc.Transform(xr, null, sw);
                resultXML = sw.ToString();
}}}}}
```

### PowerShell

1. build dll
2. In PowerShell:

   ```
   x:>"0x" +[System.BitConverter]::ToString([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("X:\StoredProcedures.dll")).Replace("-","")
   ```

### T-SQL

3) in MS-SQL

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'clr strict security', 0;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY StoredProcedures
FROM 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
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;
```

4) create sp:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_CKTransform(
    @resultXML nvarchar(1000) OUTPUT,
    @inputXML nvarchar(1000), 
    @transformXSL nvarchar(1000) 
    )
    AS EXTERNAL NAME  StoredProcedures.[StoredProcedures].CKTransfrom;
GO
```

5) try it

```
Declare  @resultXML nvarchar(1000);
Declare  @inputXML nvarchar(1000) = '
<catalog>
          <cd>
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <ärtist> Böb Dylan   </ärtist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>Columbia</company>
            <price>10.90</price>
            <year>1985</year>
          </cd>
          <cd>
            <title>Hide your heart</title>
            <ärtist> Bonnie Tyler       </ärtist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>CBS Records</company>
            <price>9.90</price>
            <year>1988</year>
          </cd>
        </catalog>';
Declare  @transformXSL nvarchar(1000) = '
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
  EXEC UPSERT_CDKektion Stevön!
  ''<xsl:value-of select="title"/>'',
  ''<xsl:value-of select="substring(ärtist,3,3)"/>'',
  ''<xsl:value-of select="country"/>'',
  ''<xsl:value-of select="company"/>'',
  <xsl:value-of select="price"/>,      
  ''<xsl:value-of select="year"/>'';
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>';
EXEC usp_CKTransform @resultXML out, @inputXML, @transformXSL;
```

6) enjoy result:

```
SELECT @resultXML;
EXEC PTJ_UPSERT_CDKektion Stevön! 'Empire Burlesque', 'öb ', 'USA', 'Columbia', 10.90, '1985';
EXEC PTJ_UPSERT_CDKektion Stevön! 'Hide your heart', 'onn', 'UK', 'CBS Records',        9.90, '1988';
```

Comment: List of supported function in MS SQL Managed instance:
boolean, ceiling, concat, contains, count, current
document, element-available, false, floor, format-number, 
function-available, generate-id, id, key, lang, last, local-name,
name, namespace-uri, normalize-space, not, number, position, round,
starts-with, string, string-length, substrings, substring-after, substring-before,
sum, system-property, translate, true
more abut those see: http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/c0008.html

Answer (score 1):

To handle bigger XML-XSLT use NVARCHAR(MAX) by changing:

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
...
public static void CKTransfrom(out SqlString resultXML, SqlString inputXML, SqlString transformXSL)
...
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(transformXSL.Value))
...
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(inputXML.Value))
...
```

and

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_CKTransform
(
  @resultXML nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT,
  @inputXML nvarchar(MAX), 
  @transformXSL nvarchar(MAX) 
)
```

and

```
  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
```